# Sklearn: pipeline transform()?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

This is my code for preprocessing train data:

```
stock_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('std_scaler', StandardScaler()),
])
train_pipelined_features_np = stock_pipeline.fit_transform(train_features_df)
```

After I trained, I was about to preprocess test data. But wonder that I have to use `stock_pipeline.fit_transform(test_features_df)` or `stock_pipeline.transform(test_features_df)`...

Since pipeline has only `StandardScaler()`, so I thought that `fit()` will not gonna do anything. So I think that `fit_transform()` and 'transform()` would do same thing. But results are different each other...

What's the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see, there are three different things: "fit", "transform", "fit_transform".

When you fit on some data, Scaler "remembers" it, so if you fit on train - parameters on train will be calculated, if you fit on test - parameters pn test will be calculated.

When you transform, you use the "remembered" parameters. So usually you fit model on train data and transform it. And then transform test data with these "remembered" parameters.

When you use fit_transform, Scaler learn parameters of the selected data and transforms it.

So to answer your question: if you use fit_transform, Scaler will scale test data based on test distribution and it will be different from train; if you use transform, then test data will be scaled as train data.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I understand it now! Then, which one is more suitable to use in this case? Do I have to use train parameter to scale test data? (I don't think so but not sure..)

Comment: It is better to use transform on test data, so that it will be scaled as train data. This way your model will be consistent.

Comment: which means "scale `test` data using `train` data's `mean` and `std`", right?